# Is there a way to see every time NSLog is called and the content of the NSLog?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ideally I'd like to setup a selector to see every time NSLog is called in my app, and to get the output of that NSLog. NSLog might be called by an SDK I'm using and I'd like to be able to see the output of those logs from within my app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Symbolic breakpoint.

Navigate to the Breakpoints tab in Xcode and use the `+` button in the bottom left corner to add one.

When the breakpoint is added, it should automatically come up with a window that allows you to enter the conditions on which you want it to pause execution. You can use `NSLog` as the symbol.

As for calling a custom function of your own, you can attempt to do that by adding an action in that breakpoint and utilise the debugger's ability to call into your own code by passing in the arguments that are available to the debugger e.g. `$arg1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I dont think it is possible to simply replace every instance of NSLog with something else... but you could do something like this:

```
#define NSLog MyLog

void MyLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
void MyLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,format);
    NSLogv(format,list);
    va_end(list);

    va_start(list,format);
    vfprintf(stderr,[format UTF8String], list);
    va_end(list);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSLog(@"hello %s\n","world");

    return 0;
}
```

My example uses 2 `va_list`s to log with an NSLog like `NSLogv` and `vfprintf` to log to an open FILE * stream (stderr in this case)... you could also probably more simply format an NSString (as vfprintf can't print NS objects)...

I tried a little bit to try to re-assign NSLog with dlsym which would be process wide, rather than just when the macro is expanded... I couldn't get it to work but I am not a dynamic linker expert.